# Can you get type specific behavior from generics in c#?

Tags: c#, generics

I think it should be pretty clear what I want to do - get an explicit specialization for `int` and `string`, and in C++ this is trivial with explicit specialization - is it possible to get this same behavior in C#? Assume I have a good reason for doing this and this is a trivial example of something broader in my program.

```
static class ReturnConstant<T>
{
    public static T FiveOrHello()
    {
        if(typeof(T) == typeof(int))
        {
            return 5;
        }
        else if (typeof(T) == typeof(string))
        {
            return "Hello!";
        }
        else
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException("OH NO");
        }
    }
}
```

Edit:

Here's the equivalent, perfectly legit c++ code:

```
template <typename T>
T giveConst();
template <>
int giveConst<int>() { return 5; }
template <>
std::string giveConst<std::string>() { return "Hello"; }
```

Comment: *Assume I have a good reason for doing this and this is a trivial example of something broader in my program.*, ignoring that sentence, what are you trying to do? There must be better solution.

Comment: I have a thing that takes parameters and returns a generic datatable, in C++, I have another thing that takes that generic datatable and returns typed information, in c++ I'd template that first thing and have it do the conversion automagically as above.

Comment: You should eloborate on that then. Your database isn't generic, if they have different types. It's an ungeneric *any object* or better `object`. Sounds like you realy need casts and probably a layer which handles different types of objects which are checked via `is`. Anyway without any real code, it's hard to give any advice.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The only thing wrong with your implementation is that the C# compiler can't verify the type cast to T.

But you can work around that like this:

```
static class ReturnConstant<T>
{
    public static T FiveOrHello()
    {
        if (typeof(T) == typeof(int))
        {
            return (T)(object)5;
        }
        else if (typeof(T) == typeof(string))
        {
            return (T)(object)"Hello!";
        }
        else
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException("OH NO");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Oh nifty! What's the function of (object) here - is it like typename in c++?

Comment: `object` is a type, and it's the root of the .NET type hierarchy.  I don't know the history, but my guess is that since no type conversion from `object` to any other type can be validated by the compiler, validation is turned off.  And casting through `object` has become an idiom for performing an unchecked-at-compile-time type conversion.

Answer (score 0):

No, it's impossible. Generic `T` for class `ReturnConstant<T>` means, that `ReturnConstant<int>` and `ReturnConstant<string>` are different types. And you can't return different types in common.

Comment: Ah, so because it's resolved at runtime, this is a cannot-differentiate-based-on-return-type-only type issue?

Answer (score 0):

A concept you may be interested in is a discriminated union; it would allow you to return either an int or a string with a single type, but you'd have to check at runtime to work out which one actually got returned:

sadly the concept doesn't currently exist in a way that can be efficiently implemented, requiring some language support, which is not yet added.

https://github.com/dotnet/csharplang/issues/113